# api key for posting to whatsapp using unificationengine

Tags: unificationengine

Hi I'd like to post to whatsApp using `unificationengine`. If I add the connector to my app entering **no_key** and **no_secret**, and then add a connection for a user, I get the response `{"status":3000,"info":"api_key invalid"}`.
The question is, where do I get a valid api_key and api_secret for posting to whatsApp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the Whatsapp Connector is currently only available to selected developers. You should write the company an email what your use case is and perhaps they'll give you early access.

Comment: Yes, that seems indeed to be the case for now. Thanks